# Detecting idle connection in server

Tags: network-programming, client-server, tcp

I have designed,programmed  and implemented a server application based on IO overlapped network programming paradigm on windows operating system. it works well with the expected performance, it is observed that in arbitrary selected clients sometimes nothing happens, the data transferring seems to be freeze. it doesn't even generate any TCP/IP error conditions such as time out or any. in this case server maintains that connection as active connection which in turn a needless resource reservation. What may be the reason for this ?? as a resolution how can i detect such connection. how can i reduce such situations 
Thankx

Comment: TCP doesn't have timeouts on connections by default. Either you need to specifically enable it (with the `SO_KEEPALIVE` option) or include some kind of "ping" or "keep-alive" message in your own protocol.

Comment: Thank x a lot. But this happens in the middle of a data transmission , the client seems to be stuck in the transfer without returning from the blocking recv. would that so_keepalive will help ?

Comment: In that case you probably need to make your sockets non-blocking and use polling (with e.g. `select`) with a timeout. If the polling timeouts then there's something wrong and you need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

> What may be the reason for this?

The client has stopped sending or receiving, it isn't clear from your question which.

> as a resolution how can i detect such connection. how can i reduce such situations?

Use a read timeout if you're reading, or non-blocking mode with a timed `select()` if you're writing.

Comment: Hello thank you all.. am sorry the question was informative. I meant that the client is infinitely waiting in recv blocking call. i resolved this with setting recv time out. am still confused why the connection become freeze after sending few kbs. but the server reports that the whole buffer has been transferred . Does it relate to the bandwidth of the network. how can i test the stability of the connection to the server